# Gnome Shell extensions: Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and the Gnome shell 3.18.5. I'm new to the whole 'Gnome Shell extension'-thing (I use my browser to install user-made extensions?) ..

So, the first time I accessed https://extensions.gnome.org I could install an extension *I think* but now it shows me a message (for example when I navigate to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/): "Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port":

[image: screenshot]

I can't seem to do anything on that website anymore. When I view an extension on the website I can't find any install button or anything (but then I'm not really sure how it is supposed to work).

I tried to install the extension "Hide Top Bar" and also have the Gnome Tweak Tool installed.

How would I install that tool with the command line?

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-hide-top-bar
```

does not seem to work (E: Unable to locate package gnome-shell-extensions-hide-top-bar)

Comment: PSA: This issue exists in 16.10 as well with the recent upgrade to Firefox 52, the answer works for 16.10 as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Ubuntu 16.04**

Well, I found the answer, I didn't have chrome-gnome-shell installed.

- I checked my Firefox extensions (type about:addons in the firefox url bar). The GNOME Shell integration was listed there.
- Click on More to read instructions:

> This extension provides integration with GNOME Shell and the corresponding extensions repository https://extensions.gnome.org  You MUST install native connector for this extension to work.
>   [...] For Ubuntu Linux package is available in ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell PPA. To install it type:
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell

- And this is what I did:

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell

Now there is a on/off slider at the top right on the page of each extension.

**Ubuntu 16.10** (additional information from [TrailRider](https://askubuntu.com/users/65969/trailrider))

`chrome-gnome-shell` is in the 16.10 repos (not sure about 16.04) so you can install it with the software center or via apt-get BUT it WILL NOT work and you will get the same error. Installing the ppa and then running apt-get upgrade will update chrome-gnome-shell to a more current version and it will work. I had some confusion after I installed and it would still give me the error so I added this info in a comment *[update: I included it in the answer for more visibility]*

Comment: +1 great answer. Let me add here that `chrome-gnome-shell` is in the 16.10 repos (not sure about 16.04) so you can install is with the software center or via apt-get BUT it WILL NOT  work and you will get the same error.  Installing the ppa and then running `apt-get upgrade` will update `chrome-gnome-shell`  to a more current version and it will work.  I had some confusion after I installed and it would still give me the error so I added this info in a comment.  You are free to add this to you answer if you wish.

Comment: Thanks @TrailRider. I included your comment in my answer for more visibility!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has this issue, check if this file exists:

`/etc/chromium/policies/managed/chrome-gnome-shell.json`

Somehow it was missing on my 16.10 system, which was fixed by adding the PPA above.